# remove overlay text from pandas boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I am trying to remove the overlay text on my boxplot I created using pandas. The code to generate it is as follows (minus a few other modifications):

ax = df.boxplot(column='min2',by=df['geomfull'],ax=axes,grid=False,vert=False, sym='',return_type='dict')

I just want to remove the "boxplot grouped by 0..." etc. and I can't work out what object it is in the plot. I thought it was an overflowing title but I can't find where the text is coming from! Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I found a work around which is to construct a new pandas frame with just the relevant list of things I want to box (removing all other variables).

```
data = {}
maps = ['BA4','BA5','BB4','CA4','CA5','EA4','EA5','EB4','EC4','EX4','EX5']
for mapi in maps:
    mask = (df['geomfull'] == mapi)
    arr = np.array(df['min2'][mask])
    data[mapi] = arr

dfsub = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I can use the df.plot routines as per examples....

```
bp = dfsub.plot(kind='box',ax=ax, vert=False,return_type='dict',sym='',grid=False)
```

This produces the same plot without the overlay.

[image: overlay text issue on plot]

Comment: It does look like it's an overflowing title.  Have you tried using df.plot(kind='box') instead? Have you tried stripping specified options out and adding them in one by one to see what is causing it?

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame you are using?

Comment: @CharlieHaley how do I do that? I tried df['min2'].plot(by=df['fullgeom']) but it just plots a single box plot of everything. What is the syntax equivalent or what I have? I've also tried to get_title() for the axes but it is empty so it must be coming from somewhere else?

Comment: See this page: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html  You have to scroll down a lot, but it has quite a few examples.

Comment: @CharlieHaley that's my point. I have looked through those examples and I did df['min2'].plot(kind='box') and it just plots one box rather than grouping it by 'fullgeom' which is what I have set "by=". e.g. df['min2'].plot(by=df['geomfull'],kind='box', vert=False) It doesn't produce the same plot as I've shown in my post which I thought it should.

Comment: Its OK I worked it out - I have to create a separate pandas frame with *only* one column representing the thing I wanted to plot. I've amended my question. It is a hacky work around which is inelegant but there it is..